# Sonata get ajax request prePersist?

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, sonata

My code:

```
   $(document).on('click','.fc-day',function () {
             var date=$(this).attr('data-date');
             console.log(date);
                 $.post("{{ path("admin_fitness_event_create") }}",{'date':date}, function (data) {
                     $("#myModal").modal('show').find('.modal-body').html(data)
                 })
             });
```

I would like sent value variable date to database via ajax, how I can do this? I tried through prePersist method, but she doesn't recognize ajax request

```
public function prePersist($object)
{

    $date=$_GET['date']; // not isset
        $object->setStart($date);
        $object->setEnd($date);



}
```

Comment: somebody help me please?

Comment: You should try to `var_dump` `$_GET`

Comment: Yes, is null.  PrePersist not read parameters passed via ajax.

Comment: any idea?  this is simple ajax request to createAtion... why it must be so difficult?

Comment: @Pablos you need to use a custom controller/action to do that, and create the event manually, otherwise you have send the mapped form defined in you EventAdmin class.

Comment: Can you show me simple exmple?